# Python Error With PutPixel

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

So im working on project that takes input from a text document and converts it into a image. But for some reason the debugger keeps giving this error message

IndexError: image index out of range

**Here is the code**

```
f1 = open(argv[1], "r")
f2 = str(f1.read())
farr = list(f2)
size1 = len(farr)
size2 = input("Size:")

size = width, height = int(size2), int(size2);
size1 + 1
#MAKING THE IMAGE
img = Image.new('RGB', size, "white" )
map = img.load()
print(map[0,0])
Rw,Gw,Bw = [255,255,255]
Rb,Gb,Bb = [0,0,0]

def Converter(num,x,y):
while int(size1) != int(num):
    if farr[num - 1: + int(num)] == ["0"]:
        img.putpixel((x,y), (Rw,Gw,Bw))
        x = x + 1
    elif farr[num -1: + int(num)] == ["1"]:
        img.putpixel((x,y), (Rb,Gb,Bb))
        x = x + 1
    elif farr[num -1: + int(num)] == [" "]:
        y = y + 1
    else:
        print("nothing")
    num = num + 1
Converter(1,1,1)
img.show()
```

Comment: I may be mistaken. But you're creating an image of size=(size2, size2) and then iterating on size1, no?

Comment: Just noticed that thanks, but that doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: There are plenty of other things wrong. But the important thing is that python is telling you that x is going past width or y is going past height.

Comment: I fixed it thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Your code is very unclear, and the indentation is off, which is very important in Python! Furthermore it is not clear what your `x` and `y` are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `gloabl x` and `global y` in the converter function and it fixes everything.